# Is there a way to enlarge part of the text without affecting to line spacing?

Tags: spacing, fontsize, line-spacing

[image]

By default, some (not all) line spacing will change to adapt the enlarged text.

I'm looking for a way to disable such line spacing change (in spite of overlapping).

Is there any?

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry, enumitem}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={6.5in, 8.5in},
}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine}

\setlength\parindent{0in}

\begin{document}
normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text\\
normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text\\
normal text, {\Huge Huge Text}, normal text, normal text, normal text\\
normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text\\
normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text, normal text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `\smash{\Huge Huge Text}`